# Is it possible to use CDI with VRaptor?

Tags: java, cdi, vraptor

Is it possible to use CDI as dependendcy injection container for VRaptor framework?

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: you means using CDI as the container provider or using CDI injection as beans for the vraptor provider?

Comment: using CDI injection as beans for the vraptor provider i guess :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently not. But VRaptor 4 will support.
More info: http://www.slideshare.net/caelumdev/vraptor-cdiideias

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now it's possible. You can use vraptor-plugin-cdi.

https://github.com/garcia-jj/vraptor-plugin-cdi

Comment: nice! but actually I was loooking for something more integrated with vraptor (this plugin allow to inject dependencies only in component factories). some people are trying to do achieve this full integration here: [link](https://github.com/asouza/vraptor)

Comment: Yeah, me too. Let's wait the VRaptor 4.